change the font size of the bottom bar of caja windows only
How can I change the size of the font in the bottom bar of caja windows without changing the global "Application font"? I mean the font that says how many items there are in a given folder and how much space is left on a given device: see the screenshot:

This font seems to be linked to "Application font", but is significantly smaller (it's probably defined as ApplicationFont.size - 3 or something like that). I would like to increase its size to match the normal size of "Application font". I'm guessing this will require editing some theme config file, but I have no idea what file exactly nor what the key for this specific font could possibly be...
